# How to update the database. After adding data from the database to the form

Tags: php, mysql

How to update the database. I will not add new records. 
The data is identical to the code retrieved from the database. I do not know how
to embed the second function, from the form and update the database.
reading from the database to the form works

```
<form action="" method="put">
  <table width="100%">
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="colsp" colspan="5">Terminarz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subcolor title-row">
      <td style="width: 10%">id</td>
      <td style="width: 40%" class="left">Gospodarz</td>
      <td style="width: 40%">Gość</td>
      <td style="width: 5%">Home<br/>Goals</td>
      <td style="width: 5%">Guest<br/>Goals</td>
   </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $hGoals = $_POST['inphomegoals'];
    $gGoals = $_POST['inpguestGoals'];
    $update="UPDATE matches SET homeGoals=$hGoals, guestGoals=$gGoals where matchID = ".$matchID;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($update);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
    }
    $display = $conn->prepare(
                              "SELECT
                                   m.matchID,
                                   hc.clubName as homeClub,
                                   gc.clubName as guestClub,
                                   m.homeGoals,
                                   m.guestGoals
                           FROM matches AS m
                           JOIN clubs AS hc ON hc.clubID = m.homeID
                           JOIN clubs AS gc ON gc.clubID = m.guestID
                           ORDER BY matchID ASC ");

$display->execute();
$results = $display->fetchAll();
foreach ($results as $index => $row){
?>
        <tr>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['matchID']; ?></label></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['homeClub']; ?></label></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['guestClub']; ?></label></td>
            <td><label><input type="number" name="inphomegoals" value="<?php echo $row['homeGoals']; ?>"/> : </label></td>
            <td><label><input type="number" name="inpguestGoals" value="<?php echo $row['guestGoals']; ?>"</label></td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
    </tbody>    
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
             <td colspan="5"><input type="submit" value="Add To Base" name="Submit" style="width: 150px; height: 45px"</td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
</table>
</form>
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php
 $db_server="localhost";
 $db_username="root";
 $db_password="";$db_database="football_db";
 $conn=new
PDO("mysql:host=$db_server;dbname=$db_database",$db_username, $db_password);  
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_` in 2018?

Comment: downloaded xampp today

Comment: Maybe I am stupid but why would you populate a form from a table then update the table with the same values that have not changed - am I missing something?

Comment: Then show me what it should look like because I do not have an idea anymore. With updated code at the top

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new button like add, name it update.

Redirect it to the the new page for better handling of code if your code is going to get bigger.

on that page do the same thing like you did above, just change your query from SELECT to UPDATE.

This is the simplest way you can do, You can avoid DRY code by using the same form and use different query for update.